# JPA OneToOne relationships returning null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have this class

```
public class Hotel implements Serializable {


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID")
    private File file;

..
}
```

and this query

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT file.hotel FROM File file   where file.id = :id ");
```

and I would like to know if it is possible to return an empty Hotel object instead of null if the hotel does not exists in the relationship but the file exists

Comment: I think you query should be more like `SELECT hotel.file from ...`. And no, you can't return an empty hotel as that would still have to be in the database. The only thing you can do is use `@PostLoad` and check if the result is null and if so, set it to an empty hotel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using JPA, you could make use of a repository. JPA can automatically return a type of `Optional<>`. Via `Optional.isPresent()` you can check if the query returned something.

A repository could look like this:

```
public interface FileRepository extends JpaRepository<File, Long> {
    Optional<File> findById(Long id);

}
```